# Assign value to slice of struct which the slice have no length

Tags: json, go, slice

I have a slice of struct to accommodate data from the database. My struct looks like this:

```golang
type TempGigs struct {
    Id           int     `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Title        string  `json:"title" db:"title"`
    UserID       int     `json:"user_id" db:"user_id"`
    Price        int     `json:"price" db:"price"`
    Currency     string  `json:"currency" db:"currency"`
    Username     string  `json:"username" db:"username"`
    ImageProfile string  `json:"image_profile" db:"image_profile"`
    Level        string  `json:"level" db:"level"`
    GigRating    float64 `json:"gig_rating" db:"gig_rating"`
    TotalReview  int     `json:"total_review" db:"total_review"`
    CreatedAt    int     `json:"created_at" db:"created_at"`
    Favorite     bool    `json:"favorite" db:"favorite"`
}
```

I want to move the data from a `[]TempGigs` to a `[]Gigs`. The `Gigs` struct is defined as:

```golang
type ResponseGigs struct {
    SectionName string `json:"section_name"`
    Offset      int    `json:"offset"`
    Limit       int    `json:"limit"`
    TotalRows   int    `json:"total_rows"`
    Gigs        []struct {
        SellerInfo struct {
            UserID       int    `json:"user_id"`
            Username     string `json:"username"`
            Name         string `json:"name"`
            ImageProfile string `json:"image_profile"`
            Level        string `json:"level"`
        } `json:"seller_info"`
        ID     int    `json:"id" db:"id"`
        Title  string `json:"title" db:"title"`
        Medias []struct {
            ID       int    `json:"id"`
            Name     string `json:"name"`
            TypeFile string `json:"type_file"`
            ImageURL string `json:"image_url"`
        } `json:"medias"`
        Price    int    `json:"price"`
        Currency string `json:"currency"`
        Rating   struct {
            AVGRating    float64 `json:"avg_rating"`
            TotalReviews int     `json:"total_reviews"`
        } `json:"rating"`
        Favorite bool `json:"favorite"`
    } `json:"gigs"`
}
```

When I iterate the `TempGigs` with `for` to copy to `[]Gigs`, there is no error while compiling. But when a request is submitted the program panics with `panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0`.
I have tried to use `append` but I don't understand how to use `append` correctly.

This is my iteration code:

```golang
tempGigs := []TempGigs{}
tempResp := ResponseGigs{}
tempResp.SectionName = "Best seller"
tempResp.Offset = 0
tempResp.Limit = 10
for i := range tempGigs {
    tempResp.Gigs[i].SellerInfo.UserID = tempGigs[i].UserID
    tempResp.Gigs[i].SellerInfo.Name = tempGigs[i].Username
    tempResp.Gigs[i].SellerInfo.ImageProfile = fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", os.Getenv("STORAGE_URL"), tempGigs[i].ImageProfile)
    tempResp.Gigs[i].SellerInfo.Level = tempGigs[i].Level
    tempResp.Gigs[i].ID = tempGigs[i].Id
    tempResp.Gigs[i].Title = tempGigs[i].Title
    tempResp.Gigs[i].Price = tempGigs[i].Price
    tempResp.Gigs[i].Currency = tempGigs[i].Currency
    tempResp.Gigs[i].Rating.AVGRating = tempGigs[i].GigRating
    tempResp.Gigs[i].Rating.TotalReviews = tempGigs[i].TotalReview
    tempResp.Gigs[i].Favorite = tempGigs[i].Favorite
}
utils.HTTPJsonSuccess(w, http.StatusOK, tempGigs)
return
```

Comment: You can't add elements to a slice without using append.

Comment: Instead of defining the content of `Gigs` inline, make type declaration for it. Then create an object of that type and append it to the slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was already answered correctly in the comments, but maybe it helps you to get some more feedback on your code.

### Extract sub types from struct(s)

`ResponseGigs` is a large struct with multiple sub-structs which makes it hard to work with. Extracting the sub-structs as extra types makes things easier.

```golang
type ResponseGigs struct {
    SectionName string `json:"section_name"`
    Offset      int    `json:"offset"`
    Limit       int    `json:"limit"`
    TotalRows   int    `json:"total_rows"`
    Gigs        []Gig  `json:"gigs"`
}

type Gig struct {
    SellerInfo SellerInfo `json:"seller_info"`
    ID         int        `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Title      string     `json:"title" db:"title"`
    Medias     []Media    `json:"medias"`
    Price      int        `json:"price"`
    Currency   string     `json:"currency"`
    Rating     Rating     `json:"rating"`
    Favorite   bool       `json:"favorite"`
}

type SellerInfo struct {
    UserID       int    `json:"user_id"`
    Username     string `json:"username"`
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    ImageProfile string `json:"image_profile"`
    Level        string `json:"level"`
}

type Media struct {
    ID       int    `json:"id"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    TypeFile string `json:"type_file"`
    ImageURL string `json:"image_url"`
}

type Rating struct {
    AVGRating    float64 `json:"avg_rating"`
    TotalReviews int     `json:"total_reviews"`
}

type TempGig struct {
    Id           int     `json:"id" db:"id"`
    Title        string  `json:"title" db:"title"`
    UserID       int     `json:"user_id" db:"user_id"`
    Price        int     `json:"price" db:"price"`
    Currency     string  `json:"currency" db:"currency"`
    Username     string  `json:"username" db:"username"`
    ImageProfile string  `json:"image_profile" db:"image_profile"`
    Level        string  `json:"level" db:"level"`
    GigRating    float64 `json:"gig_rating" db:"gig_rating"`
    TotalReview  int     `json:"total_review" db:"total_review"`
    CreatedAt    int     `json:"created_at" db:"created_at"`
    Favorite     bool    `json:"favorite" db:"favorite"`
}
```

### Create an extra function to transform `TempGig` to `Gig`

Next I'd do is create a function to convert a `TempGig` to a `Gig`. (I renamed `TempGigs` to `TempGig` as the struct only holds a single gig, not multiple):

```golang
func toGig(in TempGig) Gig {
    return Gig{
        SellerInfo: SellerInfo{
            UserID:       in.UserID,
            Name:         in.Username,
            ImageProfile: in.ImageProfile,
            Level:        in.Level,
        },
        ID:       in.Id,
        Title:    in.Title,
        // ...
    }
}
```

### Fill the response `slice`

To keep the handler code minimal, I'd also create an extra function for building the `ResponseGigs` struct. For exammple:

```golang
func toResponse(section string, in []TempGig) ResponseGigs {
    var gigs []Gig
    // or to preallocate the memory space / capacity (not the length!)
    // gigs := make([]Gig, 0, len(in))

    for _, tempGig := range in {
        gigs = append(gigs, toGig(tempGig))
    }
    
    return ResponseGigs{
        SectionName: section,
        Gigs:        gigs,
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can preallocate the length of the slice and work with indexes. I prefer the `append` approach as it is less error prone.

```golang
    // preallocate the length of the slice (not only the capacity)
    gigs := make([]Gig, len(in))
    for i, tempGig := range in {
        gigs[i] = toGig(tempGig)
    }
```

### Handler code

Finally the handler code would boil down to something like this:

```golang
    tempResp := toReponse("Best seller", tempGigs)
    tempResp.Offset = 0
    tempResp.Limit = 10
    utils.HTTPJsonSuccess(w, http.StatusOK, tempResp)
    return
```

---

Hope this helps as a next step. There are many things that can be adjusted to your liking. Happy Coding!

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped you!